# Django - automatically create User on Athlete create (tied together with a OneToOneField)

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model called Athlete that has a OneToOne relation to the User model which is an AbstractUser, I'm trying to create a user whenever I create an Athlete and automatically tie them together but I'm getting an error:

```
Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'users.User'
```

Here's my User Model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_athlete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_coach = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_owner = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.is_athlete = Athlete.objects.filter(user=self).exists()
        self.is_coach = Coach.objects.filter(user=self).exists()
        self.is_owner = Organization.objects.filter(owner=self).exists()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

and the Athlete Models (so far):

```
class Athlete(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    coach = models.ForeignKey(Coach, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='coach')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            User.objects.get(email=kwargs.get('email'))
            print('User with this mail already exists')
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            print('User with this mail does not exist')
            new_user = AuthUser.objects.create_user(email=email)
            self.user = new_user
            new_user.save()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I'm calling AuthUser.objects.create_user because User is already the name of the User class, so I import the django auth user with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User as AuthUser
```

Comment: But you subclassed `AbstractUser` and set that as user model, so that means the `User` of `django.contrib.auth.models` is no longer relevant, and you thus should create users with the `User.objects.create_user`, so with the *new* user model.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem ```django.contrib.auth.models is no longer relevant``` does this mean we can't use it's User(or AuthUser) directly anywhere? I understand it is not relevant but still curious.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Oh I see, thanks that makes sense and solved the issue. If you'd like to post it as an answer I'll accept it. Please tag me here so I get notified when it's done

Comment: Hello @shivankgtm these article will help you to understand about **AUTH_USER_MODEL** [post1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) , [post2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL)

Comment: @shivankgtm I usually add an import `from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model` then call `get_user_model()` where ever I would typically reference the User model class directly. It's easiest to just manually assign it to `User = get_user_model()` in my opinion. Then you can manage the model from `User.objects.create_user()` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You now use another model as user model, so that means that you also use this to register users, so:

```
from users.models import User

class Athlete(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    coach = models.ForeignKey(Coach, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='coach')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs, email=None):
        try:
            self.user = User.objects.get(email=email)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            self.user = new_user = User.objects.create_user(email=email)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```